# how to do gamma function and quadgk function in ADCME

Tags: julia, tensor

I am very new to Julia, and I know I can use the SpecialFunctions package to use the gamma function, but if for example, I write:

```
using SpecialFunction
using ADCME
s = Variable(1.0); c = gamma(s)
```

then I will run into the error gamma not defined, so how can I write gamma function in PyObject
My second question is that I can write

```
using QuadGK
int = quadgk(f, a, b)
```

but there is no quadgk function in ADCME, so what should I do? Should I make an estimation by trapezoid rule or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Julia 0.7+, you need to do the following:

```
(@v1.5) pkg> add SpecialFunctions

julia> using SpecialFunctions

julia> gamma(0.5)
1.772453850905516
```

and the `gamma` function will be defined.